# How to average the values of two dataframes in R cell for cell

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 2 data frames and would like to average them out cell by cell.
For example:

```r
**df1**

1 2 3
0 4 5
1 0 6

**df2**
 
0 3 1 
1 2 1
2 0 6

**df combined: average** 

0.5 2.5 2
0.5 3   3 
1.5 0   6
```

is there an efficient way to do this? ideally with the tidyverse package?

Comment: Is this average by row or column? Also, the `tidyverse` is a suite of packages. Most people really just need `dplyr`.

Comment: Try `(df1+df2)/2`

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do:

```
(df1 + df2)/2
```

Comment: Thank you, I looked up the question but idk why no one answered in a straightforward manner like this.